# php form select should trigger url change and value change

Tags: php, html

When I change the value of the `select` element, the

- Page should load
- The value based output should be echoed.
- the url Should indicate the http://mysite.com/?sort=value

HTML

```
<form name="form1" action=""  method="post">
    <select id="filter1">
        <option value="?sort=recent" onselected="this.form.submit();">Most recent</option>
        <option value="?sort=views" onselected="this.form.submit();">Most viewed</option>  
    </select>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['filter1']))
    {
        $term = strtolower($_POST['filter1']);
        switch($term)
        {
            case 'recent':
                echo "recent";
                break;
            case 'views':
                echo "by views";
                break;          
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to do some more research on how PHP and HTML work. There are so many things wrong with the code you posted that I think you lack some basic knowledge that is quite easily obtainable

Comment: Use GET method for this one,not POST.

Comment: and the reason for using get over post?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be a little confused about the process of sending data in forms. Here is the code which will work for you, based on your PHP file, and the variables it's looking to get from the querystring.

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="get">
    <select id="filter1" name="filter1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="recent">Most recent</option>
        <option value="views">Most viewed</option>  
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You can see I've changed the `method` attribute to `get`. This means the data will be sent via the querystring, so once the form is submit the URL will change to: `http://example.com/?filter1=value`

Also for the sake of redundancy, you should include a submit button for people who have javascript turned off.

Comment: why not the onchange in the select tag instead of the option tags?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<form name="form1" action="newurl.php"  method="post">
    <select name="sort" onChange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="recent">Most recent</option>
        <option value="views">Most viewed</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And remember your form method is post so the sort value will be stored on $_POST['sort']

Also, you can just change the form's method to "get" and leave the form's action value blank, since the default action behavior on post is to call the same file (let's call it form.php) with the get values attached (something like "form.php?sort=selectedvalue"), which already implies an url change, despite being the same file.

Comment: It's not at all. Don't know why someone would DV it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `onChange` event on your `select` object:

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <select name="filter1" onchange="parentNode.submit()">
       <option value="recent">Most recent</option>
       <option value="views">Most viewed</option>  
    </select>
</form>
```

The value of var `filter1` on your PHP script will be `recent` or `views`, no need to use `?sort=whatever` to send the data.

Then you must to retrieve the vars from you `POST` super-global, and not `GET` as you used. If you want to use `GET` you must change the `method` type on your form to `get`. I think using `GET` is the right way to do what you want.. so:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['filter1']))
    {
        $term = strtolower($_GET['filter1']);
        switch($term)
        {
            case 'recent':
                echo "recent";
                break;
            case 'views':
                echo "by views";
                break;          
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can somebody tell what is wrong with this to deserve a donwvote? Tell so I can fix it. @alex ?

Comment: same for me, I would also like to know what is wrong with my answer, please, if anybody can help me..